# Case Milestone Clock not appearing in Community Page Layout

Tags: community, entitlements, casemilestone, customer-community-plus

While setting up community with case entitlements, the case milestone is not visible on Community login(case detail page). The user license used is 'Customer Community Plus'.

The entitlement & case milestone are working fine & displayed properly in Admin view.

But while logging in as community plus user, the case milestone clock is not visible via page layout setup.

As a workaround, tried to view it via VF page, which is working.

What is the step need to done to make the case milestone visible in Community login page via standard setup.

**Admin View:**

[image]

**Community View using VF page:**

[image]