# Lightning Page in Community

Tags: lightning, community, napili, customer-community-plus

I have created a lightning page & enabled for certain app, profile, record type.

The page is appearing as expected in lightning experience.

My question is, can I use the lightning page (Record page) in Salesforce Community? I am using napili template for my community & license used is Customer Community Plus.

Is it possible or not? If possible, can someone tell me the steps?

Thank you very much for all your answers/comments in advance.

Comment: you can add lighting component from community builder and about adding lightning pages I am not sure haven't seen any option for that.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use lightning page in community. You need to create a community page using community builder.

Documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_create_page.htm&type=5)

1. Navigate to Setup --> Communities and click on builder against your community
   [image]
2. Create a new page in the community builder by clicking new page inside builder bottom of pages pane you will see an option to create a new page
   [image]
3. Once the page is created, drag and drop the component you wish to see in the community.If its a custom component dont forget to add the interface `implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"`to the component.

4.Publish the page by clicking publish button  on right side top of the builder and it will be visible inside the community for users.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I am trying to do is to show case milestone on Case Detail page in the Community. 
I tried below two options, but failed.
1. Created page layout with feed view, the same page layout is reflected in community but Case milestone is not appearing.
2. Tried via lightning page, not got to know it is not possible

Please advise how I can show case milestone on Case detail page in the Community

Comment: Please help: my another question related to above comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223465/case-milestone-clock-not-appearing-in-community-page-layout

Comment: checking it@Priyanka

Comment: thank you very much in advance. Its really a great help.

Comment: You can use your vf page (built on Case stnadard controller) here om community page, just pass case id as parameter {!recordId} and it would work as expected. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_use_visualforce.htm&type=5