# How to add Dynamic Related list - single to the community builder page

Tags: related-list, community-builder, dynamic

I want to add a dynamic related list- single on a page on my community site, but I don’t see how I can do this as there is no component available to drag and drop it. Also this dynamic related list - single is summer 2022 feature from salesforce.

I added this dynamic related list to the page layout in salesforce from LAB but dont know how to it on community builder.

Please let me know.

Comment: Is your community page a Lightning page?

Comment: It should be a lightning page but not really sure

Comment: does this help - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223525/lightning-page-in-community?  you may need to create a LWC for the related list to make it available in the Community Builder

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and asked in the Salesforce Community - long story short: It is not possible yet within the Community Builder and unfortunately, it is not on the near-term roadmap of Salesforce. (See whole conversation here: [Dynamic Related List - Single available in Community (Builder)](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000HFH7pSAH) )

Therefore, I created the idea on Idea Exchange to enable the Dynamic Related Lists also for Experience Cloud/ Community Builder. [Idea Exchange Post](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000KSQFWUA5/introduce-dynamic-related-list-single-in-experience-cloud-community-builder)

Hope that helps!

Cheers,
Christopher